# How to determine CR of a group of enemies?

Tags: dnd-5e, encounters, cr-calculation

I have played some games of D&D and when it comes to groups of enemies, I'm always asking myself "Does this encounter have a good CR for my group? Is it too strong/weak?".

I might have missed the point in the DMG or the MM where the formula to calculate the CR of a group of enemies is given, but since I couldn't find it, I came here to ask if someone knows it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I calculate a suitable combat encounter under 5e based on the CR values in the Monster Manual?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73361/how-do-i-calculate-a-suitable-combat-encounter-under-5e-based-on-the-cr-values-i)

Comment: @PremierBromanov answers to that question don't have guidelines for groups of monsters

Comment: This one probably more relevant, then
https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/73126/my-pcs-are-too-strong-for-a-published-adventure-how-can-i-fix-the-content-so-it?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Please review Basic Rules, 2018, pages 164-166. It's at the WoTC site for free, and has a nice, concise treatment of encounter building.

Comment: I think there are answers to building an encounter, but none for questions that ask about it per se. Might be worth answering here in depth if we've never done it before

Comment: I  have [an answer here also that is very related](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/129430/22566)

Comment: I do believe this is related, if not just helpful: "[How many enemies will challenge my party of four 1st-level characters, but not result in certain death?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/132705)"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The answer to this is slightly more complicated than I think most would like. There's no easy way to calculate the total CR of an encounter; CR is one factor used in assessing Encounter Difficulty. (Which appears to be your actual question, assessing encounter difficulty).  You (1) use CR to calculate the XP value of the encounter, and (2) then compare that to the Encounter Difficulty table (after applying the formula for multiple creatures) and (3) then compare that to the chart given on page 82 of the DMG.

#### The calculation process

Let's use level 4 characters

1. A level 4 character provides the XP thresholds of:  125 for easy, 250 for medium, 375 for hard, and 500 for deadly (**this chart is on pg 82 of the DMG**).
2. A party of 4 level 4's have the values of: 500, 1000, 1500, 2000 for easy, medium, hard, and deadly respectively. Now, you might be thinking "Oh, that's not too bad!" but we're not done here.
3. If you have 1 monster all you have to do is compare it's XP value to your formula and you're good to go! Like a CR 5 Bulette (1800 xp) is a Hard encounter for your PCs.
4. If you add more monsters page 82 provides more help in the form of  another table.

   - If you have 2 monsters you multiply their total XP by 1.5, if there's 3-6 you multiply by 2, and this continues.

#### Example Multi-Monster Encounter for that party.

If you have 3 CR 2 Ettercaps (450 XP each, modified to 2700 by formula) confront the party, it's a deadly (Probably much more than deadly) encounter for that party.

#### That same encounter for 4 5th level adventurers

From the XP Threshold table, a 5th level character's values are:
Simple: 250, Medium: 500, Hard: 750, Deadly: 1,100. (1000, 2000, 3000, 4400 for a party of four)
The same 3 Ettercap encounter is between Medium and Hard for the higher level party. (DMG suggests rounding down so it's a "Medium" encounter in this situation.

### Too much math?

I agree! There's a website called [Kobold Fight Club](https://kobold.club) that will do all this math for you! All you need to do is input party size and level and select your monsters and you can see how difficult (and how much XP they'll get!) for an encounter

Comment: I did a bit of formatting, and added the examples, to better illustrate your points.  (This is the kind of answer I had in mind to offer, thanks for saving me the work!)  +1

Comment: It’s worth pointing out that the DMG recommends not pitting the party against monsters with a CR higher than the party’s level.  So a CR 5 bulette against a level 4 party might be more deadly than the XP table implies.

Comment: Could you make the reference book and page more visible? It's buried in sentences and barely visible at a quick glance, to the point where I initially wanted to ask you to add those references before reading it entirely and finding the answer.

Comment: @ktt4d in my experience with a 4v1 the party can win an encounter that was much beyond deadly due to the action economy. Especially if you have very tactical players using haste and other buffs optimally.

Answer (score 3):

The rules for balancing a combat encounter are found in [chapter 13 of the basic rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/building-combat-encounters) or [chapter 3 of the Dungeon Masters Guide](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/dmg/creating-adventures#CreatingEncounters).

An alternative format, but using the same math underneath, is found in [chapter 2 of Xanathar's Guide to Everything](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/xgte/dungeon-masters-tools#EncounterBuilding). The play test version of this alternative format can be found in the [Encounter Building Unearthed Arcana](https://dnd.wizards.com/articles/unearthed-arcana/encounter-building).

Various online calculators can also be used, including [one from dndbeyond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/my-encounters).